# iPhone device: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios

I am having an issue when trying to load my application using the  application loader.

Getting error message when trying to load the .zip file using the application loader...

"The application wrapper must end in .app /var/folders//5g/...."

I did the Product/Archive, but Archive is gray out ....  I am not able to load my application neither from Xcode nor application loader.  I am new to iOS...  I have looked my application files and I don't see any .app file. is that it?  I have created an application by using storyboard... any tips?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Application Loader you need to upload an .app file. The ipa (or .zip) file that you have is an archive that contains an directory (`Payload`) with the .app file that has the name for your application. That's the file you need to upload from Application Loader

For uploading it from XCode you need to archive it, or go to Organize->Archives and select submit to AppStore from there.

If you have the `Archive` option disabled from the `Product` menu you need to select `iOS Device` as target in the run target drop down. You probably have `iPad/iPhone Simulator X.X` selected now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I quit the Application Loader went to Xcode(4.3.2) and I have set the run option to iOS Device then product/archive …. it ran it and created an archive BUT getting 
" warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)  "   :(

Comment: After receiving that error "The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements..."  I went to to app Build Settings/Code Signing and the Code Signing Identity/Debug /Any iOS SDK: "Don't Code Sign" then changed to "iPhone Distribution"  also the Release / Any iOS SDK: "Don't Code Sign" also changed to "iPhone Distribution"... Trying to build and NOW getting Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates "...  Man, I am very confused...  Any tips?

Comment: Have you checked your provisioning profiles (XCode, Organizer->Devices->Provisioning Profiles) ? Take a peek at the `Status`column.  Also check your certificates under teams in the same window. Last solution would be to remove them all and remove certificates from Keychain Access and re-install them and restart XCode.

Comment: The XCode, Organizer->Devices->Provisioning Profiles showing the "myApp"  with Status of Valid Profile and also a iOS Team Provision profile: * with Status of valid profile....

Comment: Now when looking under organizer-devices / Library-Provision Profile I have "myapp", "myapp distribution", and "iOS Team Provision Profile: *" all with status "Valid Profile" ...  I have noticed that my app compile and runs using the simulator but the issue is when using my device (iphone) then I get "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.".....

Comment: By the way, under Teams I have two certificates both with my name; one with type iOS Distribution and another with type iOS Development.....

Comment: I feel a bit uneasy removing certificates...  Can you provide with a save way to remove and reinstall?

Comment: I have read how to removed and reinstall it.. still not working